# android circle layout

Tags: android

I am trying to use the circle layout located at https://github.com/dmitry-zaitsev/CircleLayout

Document says, layout file should look like,

```
<ru.biovamp.widget.CircleLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@android:color/white"
  app:angleOffset="90.0">

  <!-- Add here any views you want -->

</ru.biovamp.widget.CircleLayout>
```

Can someone please post demo code or layout sample file by adding few images?

Comment: I tried adding few text views and still it is not showing it as circle.

Answer (score 1):

Following code worked and the issue is solved. Thanks for the help.

```
    <ru.biovamp.widget.CircleLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@android:color/white"
  app:angleOffset="90.0"
  app:layoutMode="pie"
  app:divider="#112233"
  app:innerRadius="40dp"
  app:innerCircle="#119922"
  app:dividerWidth="10dp"
  >

 <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="one"
      android:id="@+id/w"

  />
 <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="two"
      android:id="@+id/w1"
  />
 <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="three"
      android:id="@+id/w2"
  />
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="four"
      android:id="@+id/w3"
  />
       <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="five"
      android:id="@+id/w4"
  />

      </ru.biovamp.widget.CircleLayout>
```